# Generate FLV video with alpha channel using open source tools

Tags: video, flash, flv, transparency

I have a sequence of PNG-images **with transparency** which I want to convert to an FLV video with transparency.

So far I have been using ffmpeg to create FLVs (`vp6a`), but it doesn't seem to support alpha channels.

The only software I found so far is Adobe After Effects, but it is too pricey.
And then there is Adobe Flash Media Encoder, but it can only encode live from devices and not from file.

So is there an open source alternative that can create FLVs with **alpha channels?**

Answer (score 2):

In a browser, you can display an FLV with alpha channel with just changing some parameters.
See the following article for an example: 
[Alpha Video and HTML: How did they do that?](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=2CF0B)

If you are looking for software to do that, I don't know of any good open-source solution, but there is a low-budget commercial alternative : [Moyea Flash Video MX Pro](http://www.moyea.com/video-to-flash/) ($99.95), with a free trial for checking it out. You can watch a demo video tutorial [here](http://www.askmrvideo.com/public/259.cfm).

**EDIT**

The [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm) is said in the [Codec Guide](http://www.codecguide.com/klcp_ability_comparison.htm) to contain all the flavors of the VP6 codec : VP60, VP61, VP62, VP6A, VP6F.

Comment: thanks, but i am looking for a free tool that can create FLVs with alpha channel (VP6a codec)

Comment: @clamp: Then go ahead and download VP6 from http://www.free-codecs.com/download/vp6.htm. Google bought On2 Technologies and released it to the public. Actually, there are also VP7 and VP8, but I haven't looked into them. VP6 sounds good enough from the description.

Comment: thanks, but i am looking for VP6a, the one that supports alpha channels. (video with transparency)

Comment: @clamp: See my edit. I am also not sure that the link in my comment doesn't also contain vp6a.

Comment: The K-Lite Codec pack is mostly for *decoding*, and only does *encoding* to a small number of formats.  I don't believe VP6a is one of those.

Comment: @Simon: Correct. K-Lite supports encoding in VP7, not VP6. On2 has now released a free version in [VP6 6.4.2.0](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/vp6.htm).

Answer (score 2):

[AviDemux](http://avidemux.razorbyte.com.au/#avidemux2.5), open first Image via "File"->"Open", add following images via "File"->"Append...".

Choose "Sorenson Spark" in Video, "FLV" in Format. Configure your settings, play with filter, then Save as Video, and you're done!

Comment: thanks, but it doesnt seems as if sorenson spark supports alpha channels. i would like to encode in VP6a.

Comment: So install/incorporate the VP6a codec and use AviDemux.

Comment: ok, but the only version of vp6a i found is commercial. do you know of an open source/free alternative of it?

Answer (score 1):

I found these:

- [FLV Converter](http://worldtv.com/blog/guides_tutorials/flv_converter.php)
- [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) this is supposedly an open source software
- [on2](http://on2.com/) This supposedly has a cheap version that you can purchase.

I'm not too familiar with flv so i hope this can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, but ffmpeg is what i am using so far already, but it cannot encode in VP6 or VP6a, just h263 which doesnt support alpha.

Answer (score 1):

VP6a encoding is pretty new and therefore only supported in commercial products like [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects) and [Sorensen Squeeze](http://www.sorensonmedia.com/flash-video-encoding/).