# opensource vp6a encoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, alpha-channel

I am looking for a way to encode a movie with vp6a. I was hoping I would be able to do this with ffmpeg using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.flv -loop 1 -i bg.tga -vcodec vp6a -vframes 1037 -b:v 1024k -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=max(402\, 360*iw/ih):-1[OUT1]; [OUT1]crop=402:360 [OUT2];[1:v][OUT2]overlay[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a  -s 402x360 output.flv
```

This scales and crops the video a bit and places an image in the background. The image is bgra.

It's almost perfect, however I get the error Unknown encoder 'vp6a', indeed, vp6a is not supported by ffmpeg.

I hoped the [flix engine](http://www.on2.com/on2-video/flix-engine/) would be an option, however it is not possible anymore to get a version.

I haven't found any other encoder that encodes vp6a (other than adobe media encoder, but that one cannot place an image in the background, nor can I use it from a command line).

So, does anyone have a patch for ffmpeg? Or an open source encoder for vp6a? Or another codec with alpha that can be encoded with ffmpeg? Or a license for the flix-engine that I can use?

A similar question has been asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/180426/generate-flv-video-with-alpha-channel-using-open-source-tools), I've tried all that has been suggested there and more. The final answer in that thread states that vp6a 'is fairly new'. That isn't true anymore in the meantime, so I hope there is a solution to this problem now.

Many thanks for any help,
Alex

Comment: vp6a is supported according to my `ffmpeg -codecs` and also `avconv -codecs`. Which version are you running?

Comment: @Paul, vp6a decoding is supported in ffmpeg, not encoding.